# What is best way to start and process thousands of threads in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to implement one scenario where I may have to process thousands of threads ( counts of threads are not fixed but it may in range of 1000-5000 range ). Below is one very known way to do this implementation but I think this not a optimized way to do this.
Any other optimized way to do this ? Basically I don't want to start with a fixed thread pool size?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
  private static final int NTHREDS = 1000;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(10000000L + i);
      executor.execute(worker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A cached Thread Pool allows you to start with a non-fixed size that will expand as needed.

Please see: [Executors.newCachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--)

Code change:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

Comment: Thanks vikingsteve, this what I was looking for.